# SQL Server: Select rows in table that share value with rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched the questions but haven't been able to find an answer. Perhaps my wording may be wrong. My problem is as follows:

Given table **Users**:

```
ID      code       owner
 1       777       James
 2       432      George
 3       111        Kale
```

And table **Products**:

```
ID      product_name        code
 1             chair         777
 2             table         777
 3               fan         432
 4           monitor         777
 5              sofa         111
 6               bed         111
```

I need a query that fetches **N** number of rows from table **Users** and then fetches all rows from table **Products** that have a code matching the code of **Any** row fetched previously.

Is this possible in SQL Server? Is it optimal?

For above example if i fetch first 2 rows (owners James and George) I should get all products with code 777 and 432.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to use a `JOIN`. What have you tried so far, and what, exactly, are your expected results?

Comment: I know about JOINS but I don't know how to pass the result from the 1st select query into a second select. To be honest I'm not that experienced in sql and dont really know what to search for for this particular case

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu : On what basis, you are selecting first 2 rows?

Comment: Sorting based on id then selecting with size and offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the first *n* (here *2*) users use `TOP`. Put that in a subquery and `LEFT JOIN products` on the common code to it.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT TOP 2
                    *
                    FROM users
                    ORDER BY id) u
            LEFT JOIN products p
                      ON p.code = u.code;
```

If you want to make users, that don't have at least one product, disappear you can replace the `LEFT JOIN` by an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. Thanks. Also is this query somewhat optimal?

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu: Optimal by what criteria? At least it seems to do the job... ...so by that criteria you could call it optimal. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a common thing, called "Joins"

for example this would give you the answer:

```
Select products.product_name,users.owner FROM products LEFT JOIN users ON products.code=users.code
```

You can read more about JOINS here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: This does what I need with one: exception: I need to set an offset and use fetch next. Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: You could use an offset with the OFFSET (OFFSET 10 will skip the first 10 rows and show the 11th and further). [https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp]

Answer (score 0):

Try this with Inner join :

```
Select products.product_name,users.owner FROM products inner JOIN users ON products.code=users.code
where users.code in (777,432)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Create table #Users
(
    Id int Identity(1,1),
    Code varchar(100),
    Owner varchar(100)
)

Create table #Products
(
    Id int Identity(1,1),
    ProductName varchar(100),
    Code varchar(100)
)


insert Into #Users(Code,Owner)
Select '777','James'


insert Into #Users(Code,Owner)
Select '432','George'

insert Into #Users(Code,Owner)
Select '111','Kale'


insert Into #Products(ProductName,Code)
Select 'Chair','777'

insert Into #Products(ProductName,Code)
Select 'Table','777'

insert Into #Products(ProductName,Code)
Select 'fan','432'

insert Into #Products(ProductName,Code)
Select 'monitor','777'

insert Into #Products(ProductName,Code)
Select 'Sofa','111'

insert Into #Products(ProductName,Code)
Select 'bed','111'

select * from #products


select * from #Products Left join #Users on #Users.Code=#Products.Code Where Owner in ('James','George')
```

Comment: use identity or primary key column in `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This works even if code is not unique;

```
select * from Products where code in
 (
  select top 2 code from users order by id
 )
```

Replace 2 with the relevant N